# How to use random typing speed animation using typed.js

Tags: javascript, html

I am using typed.js. I am looking at a simple script that enables to animate a text to simulate someone typing it. 
In the script I see  **typeSpeed 30** i would like to make the animation writing at a random speed between 20-30, or even include pauses during the animated typing. 
Is there a way to randomise that?

```
$(function(){

    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: ["The text to be animated goes here"],
        typeSpeed: 30, 
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        loopCount: false,
     });
});


<center> <span id="typed"></span></center>
```

Comment: typeSpeed is in ms or s?

Comment: I don't know this library, but for your first request you can have a small function that creates a random number between 20-30, that returns the value and then use this returning value instead of the integer for typeSpeed. Regarding the second one, you should check the plugin documentation to see if they have any option to do this

Comment: From the documentation, I can see that you can pause typing like this - `<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".element").typed({
            // Waits 1000ms after typing "First"
            strings: ["First ^1000 sentence.", "Second sentence."]
        });
    });
</script>`

Don't know about randomizing the speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over each char of your string and use typed() with random speed on each letter and append the result to your html element

```
var myString = "The text to be animated goes here";
var max = 2500; //max typeSpeed you want
var min = 100;  //min typeSpeed you want

for (i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    $("#typed").append().typed({ //here you have to test to find how to append
        strings: [myString[i]],
        typeSpeed: Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min, 
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        loopCount: false,
     });
}
```

***Working solution with setTimout() instead of typed()***

```
var myString = "The text to be animated goes here";
var max = 200; // arbitrary value to be tested
var min = 0;   

function doSetTimeout(character, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#typed").append(character); 
    }, delay);
}

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min + (i * max);  //to keep the letter in good order
    doSetTimeout(myString[i], delay);
}
```